# How do I remove one side of a shapes outline?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, path, stroke

I am trying to make text with 2 different colours. I am trying to also have a white outline on the text. 
I know there's probably a way easier way of doing this.
Can anyone help me remove the middle outline

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Add a fill to the character via the **Appearance Panel**
- Set the fill to be a gradient of your two color
- Rotate the gradient 90° so its horizontal
- Select each color stop of the gradient and set the `Location` to 50%.
- Add the stroke as desired

[image]

Note you don't have to use 50% for the gradient stop location, but both stops need to be in the *same location*. If you want one color to fill more of the character, then merely change the `Location` setting for both gradient stops. Just be sure both stops have the same location value.

This is also **live type** so the character can be changed and the appearance will remain.

[image]

Comment: This is by far the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Go into outline mode via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.
- Hit <kbd>A</kbd> for Direct Selection Tool.
- Click that line in the middle and hit <kbd>DEL</kbd>. Repeat if you can still see it, as you probably have that line 2 times, from both shapes. Second time you do this, it should probably go away.
- Exit outline mode via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The green line vanishes as soon as nothing is selected. I guess your problem is the unwanted horizontal white border between yellow and red. Solve the case by building your shapes differently:

[image]

You need a base color version (=yellow) with no stroke, an extra color piece with no stroke and a stroke-only version. In the right you see how they are stacked. In Illustrator they should snap perfectly in their places if you have smart guides and snap to point ON, no other snaps!

Make a group to keep the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative method-

- I just made 3 separate rectangles and added color fills with no stroke
- select all 3 and group them (command + G)
- with this group selected open the appearance panel (window>appearance) and click "add new stroke" in the lower left corner of the panel
- from within the appearance panel, select a color and weight for this new stroke- (note the stroke alignment is only available to center so if you want to end up with 5 point stroke you set it to 10 points)
- then in the appearance panel move the stroke to below the "contents"

All is still editable

[image]